# Как конвертировать string в _bstr_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как string test конвертировать в _bstr_t c++

```
string test;
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: _bstr_t  t = test.c_str()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `c_str()`

```
_bstr_t bstr = test.c_str();
```

Читайте https://rextester.com/QTDD95158